# What is SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER in odbc_connect?

Tags: php, apache, db2, odbc

I noticed some lines of code which uses SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER in a php file which connects apache PHP server to DB2 through odbc_pconnect as fourth parameter. May I know why we are using this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

When this option is set, all of the cursor support native to the SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver can be used for the connection. The ODBC cursor library cannot be used. All cursors are implemented as server cursors.